# How to duplicate a daemon?

Tags: openbsd, daemon

I want to run two instances of dnscrypt client proxies, but I'm having trouble making them automatically start at boot. Here is what I tried:

In `rc.local`, this is the first:

```
/usr/local/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy -a 127.0.0.1:40 -u _dnscrypt-proxy -d -l /dev/null -R dnscrypt.eu-dk
```

and the second:

```
/usr/local/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy2 -a 127.0.0.1:41 -u _dnscrypt-proxy2 -d -l /dev/null -R dnscrypt.org-fr
```

I `cd` to `/usr/local/sbin` and did a `cp dnscrypt-proxy dnscrypt-proxy2` and then when I rebooted I would get `[ERROR] Unknown User : [dnscrypt-proxy2].`

Then I searched and saw this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/240470/how-do-i-duplicate-the-nobody-user) then I manually edited `/etc/passwd` and added a new user carefully copying the default `_dnscrypt-proxy` user and changed the id, as now it has these 2 entries:

```
_dnscrypt-proxy:*688:688:dnscrypt-proxy user:/var/empty:/sbin/nologin 
_dnscrypt-proxy2:*689:689:dnscrypt-proxy2 user:/var/empty:/sbin/nologin`
```

And when I reboot, the Unknown User error still persists. A quick `ls` on the folder shows me I do have duplicated the folder. `Ps aux` shows me the daemon has not started. A Google search didn't help me so I turned to the Linux experts here. My OS is OpenBSD 5.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, here's the specific answer to your question of why the unknown user error persists: The error was in how you created the user. There are more files that need to be fixed than just `/etc/passwd`.

The easiest way to properly create the user would be to simply remove that line from `/etc/passwd` and then run `adduser -noconfig -shell -/sbin/nologin` instead. (And when you edit /etc/passwd, use `vipw` instead of just `vi /etc/passwd` - see the man page for the explanation!)

**Second**, you really don't need to create a second user. You can run the same program twice without having a copy of the program or a second user to run it under. What you need to do to run a second daemon with the same user and binary, but with different settings is simple:

- Copy the init script for the daemon to one with another name. (You've already done this.)
- Edit the new init script. Keep the same path to the binary and the same username. Change **only** the options that you want to be changed!

Voilà - you're ready to run!

Comment: Thanks so much!! It worked...but now i have 2 instances with same name on `ps aux` and i can't know which is on port 40 or 41 and think this will be a problem when i run more daemons of same program like OpenVPN or want to troubleshoot something? Also I've edited with `vi` am I screwed? Thanks again, i'm just a guy who decided to run a server and just downloaded Linux without previous experience and started messing lol.

Comment: @Freedom You can run `vipw` and just double check that your password files are now in sync (when you save, it will synchronise them). If the daemon parameters are not visible in the `ps` output, you could perhaps go back to your original route of running them as different users so you can differentiate them. Or use an `rc` script and track the process IDs to tell them apart.

Comment: @Freedom To see which is which, run `ps auxw" which will use a wider output format and thus give you more information about the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. You shouldn't need to duplicate the `dnscrypt-proxy` binary - just call it multiple times with different options
2. When you created the `_dnscrypt-proxy2` user, did you also create their primary group? I see that user has a different GID than `_dnscrypt-proxy` (`689` instead of `688`) but you didn't mention copying the group. If not, create the missing group. You can do this by editing `/etc/group` and adding the missing entry (I'm guessing by copying the entry for group `_dnscrypt-proxy`).

Point **2** should fix your problem.

Comment: Well i tried to "call it multiple times" with different options, but when rebooting  the second call was being ignored, so i tried this workaround by myself...i tried following your point 2. and add the new group but the error message still persist

Comment: @Freedom How did you edit the `passwd` file? You need to use `vipw` and not just edit `/etc/passwd` otherwise the password database files will be out of sync with the plaintext password file. If you did just edit `/etc/passwd`, to fix things just run `vipw` now and make sure the entry for `dnscrypt-proxy2` is there and correct.

Answer (score 0):

from `rcctl(8)` manual page:

> The recommended way to run a second copy of a given daemon for a
>   different purpose is to create a symbolic link to its rc.d(8) control
>   script:
>
> ```
> # ln -s /etc/rc.d/snmpd /etc/rc.d/snmpd6
> # rcctl set snmpd6 status on
> # rcctl set snmpd6 flags -D addr=2001:db8::1234
> # rcctl start snmpd6
> ```